# Do I need to provide all the links in each response?

Tags: rest, hateoas

I try to follow **HATEAOS** conventions. For each response I will provide links to another page.

I understand I can provide links for next page (for record paging). My question is, do I need to provide links for common header and footer (which includes sign in/out, navigation bar, common info - about me etc.)?

Comment: I guess you missed something. You don't provide links to another page, you provide links to other resources or collections or actions. Look at Netflix API for example: http://developer.netflix.com/docs/REST_API_Conventions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should help you

http://vimeo.com/28761654

You should provide any legal next steps available based on the state of the resource.